# how to count image size in kb

Tags: php, size

how to count image size in kb

this code show randoms images and  i want to add image size in kb format

how can i add image size in all images please help me to fix this issue

thanks

```
<?php

$directory = "./*/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = '';
// create array
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }



//shuffle array
shuffle($imgs);

//select first 20 images in randomized array
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);

?>



 <table id="results">
            <tr>
            </tr>
<tr>

<?php $num_of_files = 0; $i=0; foreach ($imgs as $img):?>
<td><a href="<?php echo $img ?>" target="_blank"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="<?php echo $img ?>thumb.jpeg" width=165 height=135 /></td>
<?php if (++$num_of_files == 12)break; ?>
  <?php if(++$i%3==0): ?>
    </tr><tr>
  <?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's Memory I/O Stream.

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
// do your processing here
// now save file to memory
imagejpeg($img, 'php://memory/temp.jpeg'); 
$size = filesize('php://memory/temp.jpeg');
```

Comment: src="<?php echo $img ?>thumb.jpeg" width=165 height=135 /> here